# Index of nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had an array like this

```
var data = [
    {
      name:"Movies", 
      info: "category_name",   
      data: [   
         {
            name:"Interstellar", 
            info: "category_data" 
         },   
         {
            name:"Dark Knight",
            info: "category_data" 
         },   
      ]   
    },   
    {
       name:"Music", 
       info: "category_name",   
       data: [   
          { 
             name:" Adams", 
             info: "category_data" 
          },   
          { 
             name:"Nirvana", 
             info: "category_data" 
          },   
       ]   
    }   
] 
console.log(data[0]);
```

If I console.log ([1][0]) the answer is undefined. I want to show "Interstellar" or "category data". Which is the index of this array?

Comment: array is base on index. object is base on property name. so you could make it like. data[0].data[0].name

Comment: The Json is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

`data[1][0]` is undefined because `data[1]` is will give you the second object in the array, `data[1][0]` wont give you the first value in `data[1]`, instead, `data[1].name` will be the first value in your object. The square brackets with index are only applicable to arrays

Comment: `[]` braces are used for objects also ..... `data[1]['name']` for example. Misleading suggesting they are only for arrays

Comment: Square brackets with index, never said Square brackets with identifier

Comment: Thank you for help , I can figure it out the index